# Cannot compile SDL with Makefile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, sdl

My Makefile consists of the following:

```
CC= g++
LIBS= -lSDL

clean:
    rm  -f  a
```

It just won't compile because g++ does not take the -lSDL parameter even though I included it.

When I do `g++ a.cpp -o a -lSDL` 
directly in Terminal it compiles just fine, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a rule:

```
a: a.cpp
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Techinically, it should be `$(CXX)` rather than `$(CC)` - that way, you get the right librarys for the C++ code, and don't need to redeclared `CC = g++` (which may foul up general rules used elsewhere if it's a larger makefile).